# Intellisense not suggesting in VS 2019 for old MVC5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I opened up an old ASP.NET MVC5 project in Visual Studio 2019 and `IntelliSense` is not making any suggestions for certain things.

As you can see below, `ActionResult` was not suggested and not highlighted as a recognized keyword.

[image]

Also, even though I have my `using MyClassLibraryProject.NameSpace` is in place, `IntelliSense` is not making any suggestions about methods in that project.

If I type things out myself, my solution compiles fine and everything works.

Any idea why `IntelliSense` may not be working?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This resolved the issues I was having with inteliSense. This solution also worked with issues related to Adding a View to a Controller with older ASP .NET MVC projects. Once the new compiler was installed, I was able to add new views to the controller with right clicking and having that menu item (Add View) appear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a known issue, please check [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505489/cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret-3.html) and I tried to follow your description to test, to workaround this issue, please upgrade the package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers' to the latest version 1.3.0 and the intellisense works fine like the following:
[image]